# 'Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException' with phpunit

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

When I test my REST APIs using an app like Postman, it works fine.

However when I run phpunit I'm getting error

```
exception 'Cake\View\Exception\MissingTemplateException' with message 'Template file "Addresses/json/add.ctp" is missing.'
```

In AppController

```
$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
```

Routes

```
$routes->extensions(['json']);
$routes->resources('Addresses');
```

ControllerTest simply

```
$this->post('/addresses/');
```

Being that it is 100% API, I have no need for any views.

Comment: You need to show your controller code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FYI I had forgotten to add the serialize

```
$this->set('_serialize', ['data' => 'data']);
```